# react redux как очистить state после сохранения данных?

Tags: reactjs, redux

после сохранения данных и создания новой записи при добавлении в нее данных id продолжаются с предыдущей записи, как сделать очистку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот так пытаюсь чистить, но не работает(

```
export const reset = () => {
    return {
        type: 'RESET_DATA'
    }
}
```

```
case 'RESET_DATA' :
    return {
        state: initialState
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

проблема решилась обновлением страницы
вместо dispatch(reset) - window.location.reload()